# How to Insert a record in Azure storage account table. App closes when i run my code FIXED

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, azure-storage

How to Insert a record in Azure storage account table. App closes when i run my code? I am working on Xamarin cross platform for android and iOS using VS2017. I have published TODOITEM with .NET c# as back end language. I am following this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#retrieve-all-entities-in-a-partition)!
Here's my code (On instally Azure Configuration Manager for .NET, it's giving error. So, i've uninstalled it.)

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageUri tableStorageUri = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageUri(new Uri("https://eg.table.core.windows.net/"));

            public void adduser()    
{
try
        {
            var accountName = "eg";
            var keyValue = "SAScode";
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);
            var abc= String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=eg;AccountKey=KEYcode");
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(abc);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("users");
            await table.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

            // Create a new new user.
            Reg newuser = new Reg("regform", "uid");
            newuser.username = uname.Text;
            newuser.password = pword.Text;
            newuser.email = uemail.Text;
            newuser.firstname = fname.Text;
            newuser.lastname = lname.Text;

            Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation insertOperation = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.TableOperation.Insert(newuser);
            await table.ExecuteAsync(insertOperation);
        }
                    catch (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException ex)
        {
            rinfo.Text = "Storage Error";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                            rinfo2.Text = ex.StackTrace;
            rinfo3.Text = ex.Message;
            rinfo4.Text = ex.HelpLink;
            rinfo5.Text = ex.Source;
        }
        //await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
    }
    private Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount CreateStorageAccount()
    {
        Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
        try
        {
            var accountName = "eg";
            var keyValue = "SAScode";
            var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName, keyValue);

            storageAccount = new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, null, null, tableStorageUri, null); // 6.2.2
                    return storageAccount;

}

catch (FormatException)
        {
            rinfo.Text = "format Error";
        return null;

        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            rinfo.Text = "arg Error";
        return null;

        }
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rinfo.Text = "acc Error";
            return null;
        }
    }
private async void reg_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) {adduser();}
```

[ERROR PAGE 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hnaxc.png)
[ERROR PAGE 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKgUB.png)

THANKS in ADVANCE.
**EDITED 4th time according to Jason's advice**
**FIXED**

Comment: Which exception is causing the crash?

Comment: When i run reg_onClicked() my app closes mentioning "App isn't working". Testing on my mobile phone (KITKAT)

Comment: no Exception occuring

Comment: You are just catching exceptions and rethrowing them, which will cause the app to crash.  Use the debugger to figure out which exception is causing the crash.

Comment: Right, let me correct it.

Comment: Same as before, Alert appears saying "Unfortunately, App has stopped"

Comment: are you actually using the debugger to step through your code?  And you are only catching a small subset of exceptions, there could be a more general exception causing the crash that you are not catching?

Comment: Thanks Jason, It seems like you'll reach the error. Working on it.

Comment: It says "Table error".

Comment: "Table Error" is your error message.  You need to look at the ACTUAL EXCEPTION OBJECT that is caught and see what it is telling you.

Comment: i have acquired the error details. These are on the 2 Images in the Question named ERROR PAGE 1 & 2. Thanks for your precious time, Jason.

Comment: SOLVED: I used the 2nd account key and generated SAS from Azure Portal again. The Error is fixed. Now I have changed the async INSERT USER function to void. and called void function in the async reg_OnClicked function. Jason's debugging strategy helped me alot.